# Can't keep footer down on mobile

Tags: css

I'm having problems keeping the footer at the bottom of the page when viewing on mobile. It currently looks like this -

[image]

I followed [this site](http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) (code below) on how to keep the footer down, which worked on desktop but not on mobile -

```
 html,
 body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
 }
 #wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
 }
 #header {
background:#ededed;
padding:10px;
}
#content {
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-top: 50px;
}
#footer {
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
 }
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28sz7g2f/2/).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to keep the `footer` at the bottom of the page.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* use margin-bottom from footer height */
  margin: 0 0 100px 0;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* set the footer height corresponding to the body margin-bottom */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Set the height but It's still just floating in the middle of the screen

Comment: Did you set `min-height: 100%` on `html` only? Do not set it on the `body`. Can you post a fiddle with your HTML and CSS?